# Can I write $M \neq N$ as $\lnot(M\subset N \land N\subset M)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve something, and I am not sure if I have a correct solution.

I have $M \neq N$, and my presumption is that $M \neq N \Leftrightarrow \lnot(M = N)$ so I wrote it like this $\lnot(M\subset N \land N\subset M)$.

Is this correct?

thanks

Comment: Yes, if $M$ and $N$ are sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. It is better to use the $\subseteq$ sign because the sign $\subset$ means proper subset. The equality of two subsets is defined as
$$A=B \Longleftrightarrow (A\subseteq B \wedge B\subseteq A),$$

meaning that $A\neq B$ is equivalent to $\neg(A\subseteq B \wedge B\subseteq A)$

Comment: The notation $\subset$ and $\subsetneq$ is also usually used (this is a comment for the OP :) ).